# How to solve Error : maximum recursion depth exceeded / i get error when use wizard forms in view.py

Tags: python, django

i try create a view with SessionWizardView in django than create a conditional steps so i create a function for condition step (in function use self.get_cleaned_data_for_step) than get error
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

```
# my code view.py is :

class ProfileUser(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'files'))
    login_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'gyms/profile.html'
    STEP_ONE, STEP_TWO, STEP_THREE, STEP_FOUR = '0', '1', '2', '3'

    def check_type_user_master(self):
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        print(data)
        if data.get('type_user') == 'M':
           return True
        return False

    def return_true(self):
        return True

    condition_dict = {
        STEP_ONE: return_true,
        STEP_TWO: return_true,
        STEP_THREE: check_type_user_master,
    }

    form_list = [
        (STEP_ONE, FormLocationStepOne),
        (STEP_TWO, ChoiceTypeUser),
        (STEP_THREE, FormMasterStepTwo),
    ]


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback? On which call is the recursion depth reached?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When use self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') get this error

Comment: Exception Type: RecursionError at /profile/
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded